# Why onMouseUp is not fired?

Tags: flashdevelop, haxe, createjs

I tried a simple example for createjs, yet, the onMouseUp event is not fired, what would be the reason?

[Here](https://github.com/nickalie/CreateJS-Haxe/blob/master/examples/Simple/src/Main.hx) is the example I tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure, but I don't know if that syntax will work:

```
_stage.onMouseUp = stageClickHandler;
```

I always prefer to add an event listener in Haxe:

```
_stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stageMouseUpHandler);
```

Comment: It worked by:
stage.addEventListener("stagemouseup", handleMouseUp); do you know why we need stage.enableDOMEvents(true); ??

Comment: Hmm, not sure about the enableDOMEvents. Maybe try asking that as a separate question. Would be interested to know.